# Python requests - how to set default retries object for created sessions?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'd like to force all requests to retry on some 5xx HTTP status codes. What I would do is:

```
retry = requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry.Retry(
        total=20,
        backoff_factor=0.1,
        status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504],
        method_whitelist=frozenset(['GET', 'POST']))
for adapter in session.adapters.values():
    adapter.max_retries = retry
```

But I need to do it for existing code with a lot of different sessions in different modules/packages. Some of them use `s = Session(); s.get()`, others use `requests.get()`. So, I'd like to force them all to use this `Retry` instance.

Is it possible to do it on `requests` package level (by initializing, setting up, simple monkey patching `requests` package)?

```
import requests

# Initialize/setup/patch requests package.
???

# Following should retry on server errors:
requests.Session().get('http://httpstat.us/500')
requests.post('http://httpstat.us/500', data={})
```

I tried to set `requests.adapters.DEFAULT_RETRIES` to `retry` object. But this is not how it works...

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import logging


logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')


def forceretry(max_retries):
    """ Decorator for `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter.__init__`. """
    def decorate(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.max_retries = max_retries
        return wrapper
    return decorate


max_retries = requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry.Retry(
        total=20,
        backoff_factor=0.1,
        status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504],
        method_whitelist=frozenset(['GET', 'POST']))

func = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter.__init__
requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter.__init__ = forceretry(max_retries)(func)

requests.post('http://httpstat.us/500', data={})
```

It forces `Retry` object for every Session (doesn't set default one). But it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) algorithm.

Here is a nice package that provides a decorator for you: [backoff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backoff/1.3.1). Can be used with `requests`.

Code sample from package documentation:

```
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo,
                      requests.exceptions.RequestException,
                      max_tries=8)
def get_url(url):
    return requests.get(url)
```